# stuck inside 'if' test: part of another code

Tags: c++

Following is part of a previously asked code which I'm trying to optimize. This is not part of any app, just trying to make it better in terms of user context. How can make the `if` clause work `Line 4` with minimal code, so that if user inputs any *integer* the test succeeds(I want to do it with `if` only). You know I'm trying to make out of long `if` clause.

```
int n;
cin >>n;
if(n ==  (0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9))
// if n is integer
    cout<<"succeeded";  //Line 4
else
    cout<<"failed";
```

Comment: Something like `if(n >= 0 && n <= 9)`?

Comment: thanks, got it, stuck while feeling sleepy

Comment: Wait, what type is `n`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n ==  (0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9)
```

This doesn't mean what you think it means. That big logical `or` chain will all just collapse to `true`, so you're really checking if `n == 1`.

You probably just want this:

```
n >= 0 && n < 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Just declare n as an integer variable. That way the input either won't be read at all or just a 0 if the user enters anything else.